# Radius of convergence of the following series

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Find the Radius of convergence of

1. $f(z)=\sum\dfrac{e^{n^2}}{n}z^n$
2. $ g(z)=\sum n\log nz^n$

$1.a_n=\dfrac{e^{n^2}}{n}\implies a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\dfrac{e^n}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}\to \infty $.Hence $R=0$

$2.a_n=n\log n\implies \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=
\dfrac{n\log n}{(n+1)\log(n+1)}\to 1$.Hence $R=1$

Can anyone please help me to check whether these are correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are perfectly correct. Additionally, in the second point we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(1+1/n)\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}}=1$$

Because $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/(n+1)}{1/n}=1$$